# Click-through markers and polylines in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

In Leaflet, is it possible to define a marker or polyline with {clickable:false}, so that a click is passed through to whatever lies beneath - be it the map or a clickable geometry object?

At the moment I solve this problem by making the marker/polyline clickable and passing the event onwards myself. But this leads to the mouse cursor always showing as the hand symbol. Ideally, the mouse cursor should look like the normal pointer or the hand, depending on whether what is beneath the marker/polyline is clickable.

Comment: why don´t you just try it instead of asking? The answer is "yes", that's the behaviour of `{clickable:false}`, as defined in the documentation

Comment: Because I tried it before asking? Your answer is simply wrong. In my test case I have a polyline object, that is clickable and a multi-polyline object directly above it (effectively highlighting some parts ob the polyline), that is not clickable. And while the mouse is above the multi-polyline, you cannot click through the polyline beneath.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/dP9aG/19/

Comment: Ok, you're right, the click will not pass through the underlying polyline, the map will receive the click.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but you can use featureGroups to have all of your clickable polylines come to the front so that the actions are surfaced.

```
var lg_noclick = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(map);
var lg_click = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(map);
// Add lines
lg_click.bringToFront();
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dP9aG/32/)

Also if you can afford to know your lines before hand, correct ordering of when you add the lines it will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not ideal but it suited my situation just fine, so it might be good for you as well.

This hides the icon and brings it back after a second using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events:

```
$('.leaflet-marker-icon').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});

$('.leaflet-marker-icon').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).delay(1000).show(0);
});
```